# Aggregating Applications Question for my Business

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I am new to the iPhone application world, so any help/information that you can offer is greatly appreciated. I am looking to take several of the top applications in a category and combine them by creating one launcher app. My questions are as follows:
1. Is it possible to combine the compiled binary files for each app, and create a launcher app that installs all of the separate programs. This assumes that the developers of each app are willing to sell/license me their binary files. Or, do I need to get the source code to make my launcher application?
2. Will Apple approve of my launcher application?

If anyone out there has an answer to my question, please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer NO.

You can't make a launcher for binary apps, you would have to get the source. Even then Apple probably won't approve it as it doesn't like people making another "desktop/springboard" type app/interface. Since you would need the source (and it won't be trivial even then) no devs are going to want to give you that.

Don't waste your time on this. Come up with a app idea that is unique, or does something better then other apps out there, don't just try to wrap existing apps with yours.

This assumes you want it to be an officially sanctioned app. If jailbreaking is an option to you, I don't know if its possible then...